# Padding issue with Thumbnail Image Class?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add an image grid to a Boostrap exercise. I am a beginner, and I am adding the images as img-thumbnail class but the images do not have any spacing in between them.

Is this a padding issue?

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6"> <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6 rounded float-right"> <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6 rounded float-left"> <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6 rounded float-left"> <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6 rounded float-left"> <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6 rounded float-left"> <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
    
    
        </div>
    </div>
```

It's coming up like the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dyvP.png).

Comment: Add a margin to the image.  But an example of what code you have tried would be a big help.

Comment: it would be better if you add your code to the question

Answer (score 1):

Yes It's padding issue.

`.img-thumbnail` is giving 4px padding around images.

Add this to your css:

```
   .img-thumbnail { 
      padding: 0;
   }
```

See Example:

```css
.img-thumbnail { 
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6"> <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6 rounded float-right"> <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6 rounded float-left"> <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6 rounded float-left"> <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6 rounded float-left"> <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="col-3-lg col-xs-6 rounded float-left"> <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG/1200px-A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt=""> </div>
    
    
        </div>
    </div>
```